# HttpURLConnection в цикле слишком долго работает, как ускорить?

Tags: java

Есть массив ссылок по которому я прохожусь в цикле, из этого массива ссылок мне нужно достать первую которая ответила статусом 200, вот что я для этого делаю:

```
String[] urls = {some urls...};
URL url;
HttpURLConnection http;
String goodResult = "";
for (String s : urls) {
            url = new URL(s);
            http = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (http.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                goodResult = s;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Можно ли как то оптимизировать этот процесс и как то ускорить запросы?

Comment: Запускать их пачками параллельно. Это трудно назвать оптимизацией, но ускорит получение первого HTTP 200. Сколько может быть ссылок?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja примерно 50+ ссылок, а что нужно для того чтобы их параллельно запускать?

Comment: Например 5 потоков и пачками по 5 запускайте. Одна пачка будет исполняться не дольше чем самый медленный запрос в ней. Будет точно быстрее.